# Are there any ways in which we can get more users to visit History meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

Looking at the posts over the past couple of weeks, it's evident that getting more people to visit meta, taking a little time to inform themselves and to see what others' concerns and opinions are, would lead to a better community.

As I recall, when I first joined History beta, it took a while for to realise the relevance and real purpose of meta. It's just not very visible.

Is there anything we can do about this? By this I mean, what scope do we have for 'advertising' it, even if that just means having the word 'meta' in a large font and more prominently displayed (but hopefully we could do more than that)?

Comment: We can't modify the CSS style of the site. Short of linking it to people directly there's not much we can do.

Comment: Obligatory [Meta Is Murder](https://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/) comment.

Comment: I wish! It seems to be only the usual suspects who visit Meta - and if you're on the mobile site it's not even mentioned. Took me a while to find it.

Comment: @yannis - There may well be something to that. We currently have several (5? 6?) active meta threads (see "FEATURED ON META" box, likely to the right of this comment), where we normally have 1 or 0. Since this happened, I've noticed we're getting 2-3 less questions per day...

Comment: @T.E.D. Coincidence perhaps? I can't speak for others but I' don't see many people who ask questions using meta. For myself,  I've dropped off a bit on 'question asking rate' but that's because I'm not going to ask something unless (a) I really want to know the answer, and (b) I'm reasonably happy with the question.